# vs code - always open a folder in a new window/workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to vs code, really impressed for the most part. One minor nit that I haven't found a solution for: with Sublime Text, and other editors, if you have an editor window already open, and do File->Open for a folder, it will open a new editor window for that folder.

With vs code, it adds the new folder to the existing window/workspace. Is there a setting to make it always open a new window? My current workaround is to first open a new window and then open the folder from that window. NBD, but a little tedious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you go the settings (you can do that by pressing ctrl+shift+p and searching for "Preferences: open user settings"), go on and search for "window.openFoldersInNewWindow" setting. You can set it to on, so it would open the folder in a new window[image]

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly. It's a bit non-intuitive how you would find the setting to search for (so thank you), it's a learning experience as with everything else.

Comment: Glad it helped. I would recommend getting used to using and navigating the settings files for vscode and it's extensions, it's very highly customizable and being comfortable with that freedom really helps!